# Building a pergola against a garage - can I attach a ledger board to garage door header?

Tags: garage, construction, pergola

I'd like to attach a pergola to my garage, and add a yard-facing door as well. Here is an annotated picture of my garage:
[image: garage with some annotations for future ledger board and door]

I wrote "roll door" on the picture, but in case it matters, I am open to other styles of door. But I want it to be wide. From online "how to build a pergola" sources ([here](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/patios/23150414/pergola-installation), for example) I gather that the ledger board should be lagged to a rim joist, but of course there isn't one here.

Is it a reasonable idea to attach the ledger to the header that I'll have to add for the door? If so, should I build the door header any differently that I would if I were just adding the door? The pergola would be otherwise supported by two posts set on concrete footers which are about 10 feet away from the garage.

Comment: Obviously the header/ledger would need to be bigger than just a header as it's carrying more loads...and it needs to be **longer** than the door is wide so it can be supported by posts on the ends, not as drawn here.

Comment: Since you're going to need a new header anyway (probably) to accommodate the bigger opening for the door, and since the load from the pergola will just be dead load from the materials (no snow load), calculate the size of the header appropriately and attach the rafters for the pergola right to the header.

Comment: Agreed. This isn't a deck. You can attach it to w/e you want. Also, Cubs or Sox? ;) Ideally, the pergola that will last 10y has nothing to do with the 20y siding except caulking a few holes where some bolts went.

Comment: I'd just joist hang the two end beams, unless you're dead set on all the boards running parallel to the clothes line. That's the only reason you'd need an extra ledger.

Comment: Thanks, all. Those are helpful comments. @Mazura: my answer is "neither" which fear is the most shameful answer from a Chicago perspective. I'm a transplant and have never developed local fanhood.

Comment: The only wrong answer is a Packers fan.